# Extracting folder, filename and extension from path

Tags: r, regex, backreference

I have a data frame containing file paths and names formatted as follows:

```
files_list <- c(
  "C:/User/Name/Folder/Subfolder1/Sub-subfolder/file.txt", 
  "C:/User/Name/Folder/Subfolder1/Sub-subfolder/file - Copy.txt",
  "C:/User/Name/Folder/Subfolder1/Sub-subfolder/file (1).txt",
  "C:/User/Name/Folder/Subfolder1/Sub-subfolder/file - Copy (2).txt",
  "C:/User/Name/Folder/Subfolder1/fileB.txt",
  "C:/User/Name/Folder/file.C.txt",
  "C:/User/Name/Folder/file-D.txt", 
  "C:/User/Name/Folder/file",
  "C:/User/Name/Folder/file Z.txt", 
  "C:/User/Name/Folder/file - backup.txt"
)
```

Every file has a parent folder and a name. These names may include one or more periods "." and/or dashes "-". In addition, some have a "Copy" notation, number designation, and/or file extension. I want to convert the data to something that looks like this:

```
[1]  "Sub-subfolder   file   txt"
[2]  "Sub-subfolder   file   Copy   txt"
[3]  "Sub-subfolder   file   1   txt"
[4]  "Sub-subfolder   file   Copy   2   txt"
[5]  "Subfolder1   fileB   txt"
[6]  "Folder   file.C   txt"
[7]  "Folder   file-D   txt"
[8]  "Folder   file"
[9]  "Folder   file Z   txt"
[10] "Folder   file - backup   txt"
```

This is the code that I think should do the trick:

```
sub(
  "(^.:/)([^/.]+/)*([^/.]+/)([^/]+)(\\s-\\sCopy)?(\\s\\(([0-9]+)\\))?(\\.([^.]+))?$", 
  "\\3   \\4   \\5   \\7   \\9",
  files_list
)
```

But what I get is this:

```
[1] "Sub-subfolder/   file.txt         "           
[2] "Sub-subfolder/   file - Copy.txt         "    
[3] "Sub-subfolder/   file (1).txt         "       
[4] "Sub-subfolder/   file - Copy (2).txt         "
[5] "Subfolder1/   fileB.txt         "             
[6] "Folder/   file.C.txt         "                
[7] "Folder/   file-D.txt         "
```

The slashes "/" and extra spaces I can deal with, but the "Copy" notations, number designations, and file extensions are not being set apart as I expect.

Any suggestions on how to identify the "Copy" notations, number designations, and file extensions? Or should I just identify the parent folders in one line of code and separate the rest in another line?

(Ultimately, I'm going to convert these text strings into a data frame with the folder, filename, copy designation, and extension are separate columns. I'm pretty sure I could do this with `tidyr::separate`, but even that requires an understanding of regex, and I want to learn how to use `()` and back references.)

Comment: Don't clarify the question with a comment. **Edit** the question to clarify it. Delete the comment.

Comment: `dirname`, `basename`, and `tools::file_ext`

Comment: I was *looking* for `tools::file_ext`, I keep forgetting that `tools` is not by default in the search path. (But the hard part of this question, I think, are the special-cases of `Copy` and numbers and such.)

Comment: Josh, whatever are you using this abstracted single-string thingamajig for? It's not columnated, so tabular format doesn't work well (or consistently); it doesn't support file access, so automation is out; ... ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help:

```
library(tools)
as.data.frame(cbind(dirname(files_list), file_path_sans_ext(basename(files_list)), file_ext(files_list)))
#                                            V1              V2  V3
#1 C:/User/Name/Folder/Subfolder1/Sub-subfolder            file txt
#2 C:/User/Name/Folder/Subfolder1/Sub-subfolder     file - Copy txt
#3 C:/User/Name/Folder/Subfolder1/Sub-subfolder        file (1) txt
#4 C:/User/Name/Folder/Subfolder1/Sub-subfolder file - Copy (2) txt
#5               C:/User/Name/Folder/Subfolder1           fileB txt
#6                          C:/User/Name/Folder          file.C txt
#7                          C:/User/Name/Folder          file-D txt
#8                          C:/User/Name/Folder            file
```

Comment: your way is much smarter than mine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I still do not know whether you need them as a string: like below

```
gsub("[/().]| - "," ",sub(".*?([^/]+/[^/]+$)","\\1",files_list))

[1] "Sub-subfolder file txt"         
[2] "Sub-subfolder file Copy txt"    
[3] "Sub-subfolder file  1  txt"     
[4] "Sub-subfolder file Copy  2  txt"
[5] "Subfolder1 fileB txt"           
[6] "Folder file C txt"              
[7] "Folder file-D txt"              
[8] "Folder file"
```

If you just need one pattern then:

```
pattern="[^/]+(?=/[^/]+$)|\\w+(?=[ ).-])|\\w+$"
regmatches(files_list,gregexpr(pattern,files_list,perl = TRUE))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7Gc9zC/1)

Comment: your `gsub` code does exactly what I asked for. Unfortunately, I forgot to include a sample file with a space " " in it. I'm playing with your code to see if I can make it work. Thanks.

Comment: @Josh Where did you leave that out?

Comment: I added it to the example after you replied. Your code deals with a space " " appropriately, but your code fails with another filename I forgot to include in the original example, but have since added: " - " that is not followed by "Copy". Sorry, I keep thinking of potential filenames that would complicate what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this isn't the best way to do this. I've realized that my question was incomplete, and I want to make the question more complete while also sharing the solution I came up with.

I want this code to deal with the full range of possible name structures:

1. file in "C:/" or any other directory/subdirectory
2. file name with any of the following characters/features

   - "." before the "." at the start of the file extension
   - "-" or " - " not part of " - Copy"
   - " " or "(" not part of " (number)" at the end of the file name

I used this code to generate example file names/paths cover all folder/name/Copy/number/extension combinations:

```
files.df <- expand.grid(
    c("C:/"), 
    c("", "F1/", "F1/F2/"), 
    c("folder/"), 
    c("file"), 
    c("", " space", "-dash", " - spacedash", ".period", ".firstperiod.secondperiod"), 
    c("", 1, " 1", 10, " 10"), 
    c("", " - Copy"), 
    c("", " (1)", " (10)"), 
    c("", ".999", ".aaa"), 
    stringsAsFactors = F
)

for (i in 1:nrow(files.df)) {
    if (!exists("x")) {
        x <- vector(mode="character", length=0)
    }
    x[i] <- paste(as.character(as.vector(files.df[i, ])), sep = "", collapse = "")
}
```

Through a lot of trial and error using ([regex101](https://regex101.com/), thanks @Onyambu!), I put together the following ridiculous regex that actually works:

```
sum(grepl(
    "^.:/(([^/]+)(?=/)/?)*(?<=/)(([^/](?! - Copy| \\([0-9]+\\)|\\.[^/\\.]+$))+.)( - )?((?<= - )Copy(?= \\([0-9]+\\)(?=\\.[^/\\.]+$|$)|\\.[^/\\.]+$|$))?( \\()?((?<= \\()([0-9]+)\\)(?=\\.[^/\\.]+$|$))?\\.?((?<=\\.)([^/\\.]+))?$", 
    x,
    perl = T
))
[1] 1620

length(x)
[1] 1620
```

Unfortunately, this regex includes 10 capturing groups, and I can only backreference 9 of them (and #10 is the file extension). So I'll be using @RHertel's much more elegant solution. But if anyone sees a way to reduce the number of capturing groups, let me know!